# How can out the total expenditure for each poly with group by?

Tags: sql-server

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

when running this code:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(Times.bulan AS VARCHAR(7)) AS bulan, 
    CAST(FinanceFact.id_poli AS VARCHAR(7)) AS IDpoli,  
    SUM(FinanceFact.Pengeluaran) AS TotalPengeluaran
FROM 
    FinanceFact 
LEFT JOIN 
    Times ON FinanceFact.id_time = Times.id_time
GROUP BY
    (CAST(Times.bulan AS VARCHAR(7)),
     CAST(FinanceFact.id_poli AS VARCHAR(7)))
```

I want to bring out the total expenditure for each poly based on the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is caused by extra parentheses in the last line.
Try:

```
GROUP BY CAST(Times.bulan AS VARCHAR(7)),CAST(FinanceFact.id_poli AS VARCHAR(7))
```